# Rails and exporting a console query to csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have the following query I am running...

```
require 'csv'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment.rb'

file = "#{Rails.root}/public/data.csv"
registrations = OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 681).where(status: "Completed").where("score >= ?", "80").where("exam_completed_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 3.years.ago, Date.today)
 
CSV.open( file, 'w' ) do |writer|
  writer << registrations.first.attributes.map { |a,v| a }
  registrations.each do |s|
    if s.user_id
        writer << User.find(s.user_id).email
    end
    writer << s.attributes.map { |a,v| v }
  end
end
```

This is failing on the line  `writer << User.find(s.user_id).email` with the error:

```
`<<': undefined method `map' for "my_user@yahoo.com":String (NoMethodError)`
```

Basically, I just want to add a column with the users email address in it.

## Update

Here is the current output w/out the email field

```
id  cart_id user_id course_class_id created_at  updated_at  exam_attempts   exam_completed_at   evaluation_completed_at status  score   add_extension   retest_cart_id  retest_purchased_at
11990   10278   6073    681 2014-10-30 20:34:18 UTC 2014-12-17 14:48:39 UTC 2   2014-12-17 03:16:44 UTC 2014-12-17 14:48:39 UTC Completed   90  FALSE       
11931   10178   6023    681 2014-09-02 22:35:08 UTC 2015-02-24 03:58:03 UTC 1   2015-02-24 03:56:12 UTC 2015-02-24 03:58:03 UTC Completed   80  FALSE       
12015   10316   6089    681 2014-11-15 14:31:05 UTC 2014-11-18 20:14:13 UTC 1   2014-11-18 20:11:46 UTC 2014-11-18 20:14:13 UTC Completed   82  FALSE       
12044   10358   6103    681 2014-12-03 15:56:39 UTC 2014-12-06 23:05:18 UTC 2   2014-12-06 23:02:13 UTC 2014-12-06 23:05:18 UTC Completed   94  FALSE
```

So I would like to append an email field to each of the colums above.

Comment: Whats the actual desired result? You want a CSV file with just a email column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty ghetto. But full disclosure, it's an adhoc report a customer is requesting and it does what they need it to. I just concatinated `[User.find(s.user_id).email]` onto the `writer` statement. Looks like simply wrapping brackets around it is enough to do the trick. Here is the full code...

```
require 'csv'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment.rb'

file = "#{Rails.root}/public/data.csv"

registrations = OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 681).where(status: "Completed").where("score >= ?", "80").where("exam_completed_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 3.years.ago, Date.today)

CSV.open( file, 'w' ) do |writer|
  writer << registrations.first.attributes.map { |a,v| a }
  registrations.each do |s|

    writer << s.attributes.map { |a,v| v } + [User.find(s.user_id).email]
  end
end
```

Comment: You still have a `n+1` query issue in there. You can also just do `writer << registrations.first.attributes.keys.push('email')` to get the columns.

Comment: `writer << s.attributes.values.push(s.user.email)` is also miles better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CSV, but I infer that `writer <<` calls `map` on whatever is to the right of `<<`. A string doesn't respond to `map`. And, `User.find(s.user_id).email` is a string.  So you get the error.

I suppose you could build an `array` that includes the email address and then call:

```
writer << array_with_email_in_correct_location
```

on it. But that seems weird because I think you'd end up with a row with just an email address. Unless that's what you want.

With out seeing some sample data and a desired result, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have defined an association and use it:

```
class OnlineCourseRegistration
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :online_course_registrations
end
```

One major problem with your code is that:

```
User.find(s.user_id)
```

Will cause one additional DB query per row returned from `online_course_registrations` which is really slow.

So you want to join the rows.

```
registrations = OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 681)
                                        .joins(:user)
                                        .where(status: "Completed")
                                        .where("score >= ?", "80")
                                        .where(exam_completed_at: (3.years.ago.. Date.today))
```

You could get the attributes plus the user email by doing:

```
registrations.map do |r|
  r.attributes.values << r.user.email
end
```

`attributes` returns a hash. `Hash#values` returns the values as an array. We then push the email on the end of the array. Easy peasy.

But using `.pluck` to get the values straight from the db is far more effective in the first place:

```
columns = OnlineCourseRegistration.column_names.map {|c| "#{OnlineCourseRegistration.table_name}.#{c}" }.push('users.email')

registrations = OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 681)
                                        .joins(:user)
                                        .where(status: "Completed")
                                        .where("score >= ?", "80")
                                        .where(exam_completed_at: (3.years.ago.. Date.today))
registrations.pluck(*columns)
```

To output to csv you would do:

```
CSV.open( file, 'w' ) do |csv|
  registrations.each {|r| csv << r }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

either `registrations.first.attributes` or `s` are string.

`String` class does not have a `:map` method

if you need more help add more info

Comment: `2.3.1 :001 > {}.respond_to?(:map) => true`

Comment: @jvillian `:map` is not included in the `Hash` class, but in the parent `Object` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-tap

Comment: To be precise, [Hash](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) does not define `:map`. However, `Hash` does include [Enumerable](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Enumerable.html) and `Enumerable` defines `:map`. So, I suppose one could say that `:map` *is* included in the `Hash` class. It is not correct, I believe, to say that `:map` is included in the parent [Object](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Object.html) since `Object`, like `Hash` does not define `:map` nor does `Object` include `Enumerable`.

Comment: @jvillian you are right. Interesting. Yes, it probably `include` the `Enumerable` Module